# How can I write a list of multiple tensors into a .txt file?

Tags: python, list, tensor, txt

I've got a list `tensors` containing multiple tensors. I want to write all tensor values in a text file.
I already have this approach:

```
with open('tensors.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write('{0}\n'.format(', '.join(str(n) for n in tensors)))
```

It gives the following output:

```
tensor([[1.9946e-02, 1.4917e-02, 3.2765e-02,  ..., 1.6152e-02, 2.4134e-02,
         1.8119e-02],
        [6.0340e-05, 2.4706e-02, 8.8531e-03,  ..., 8.4259e-03, 4.2288e-03,
         1.6180e-02],
        [1.4888e-02, 3.1763e-02, 3.6018e-02,  ..., 4.5888e-03, 1.0974e-02,
         1.8538e-03],
```

Is there a way to only save the values without the brackets, the line breaks and the labelling as tensor?

I've tried to realize this with json, but the "Object of type Tensor is not JSON serializable".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pickles aren't meant to be read (other than by Python itself).

Comment: Thanks, I don't knew that.